# Android seamless audio loop

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to seamlessly loop an audio file. I was using MP3 which I discovered that MP3's can't loop seamlessly due to silent lead-in in the file.

Now tried the following code using OGG and WAV. Sound loops but there is a small (but noticeable) delay between:

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
            descriptor = getAssets().openFd( "rain30s.ogg" );
            mp.setDataSource( descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength() );
            descriptor.close();
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
```

OGG and WAV repeat seamlessly in Audacity.

Can anybody help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet (when sticking to the API) would be a SoundPool.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: I have read that SoundPool has memory problems (can't remember the specifics though). I will be looping a 3 seconds file, but the user can decide how long for. If it was an hour, would there be a problem using SoundPool?

Comment: I've not heard about any memory problems when using a sound pool. In fact its purpose is to load audio files into memory for nearly instantaneous playback for games and such :)